# Question on commutativity of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

For part (a):
[image]

I’m not sure where to go on part (b).
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you explicitly calculate $ AB - BA $ you will find that its trace is 0. Thus $ [A,B]^2 = kI_2 $ from which the result follows.